# Prestashop 1.6: error 404 en páginas que se muestran bien

Tags: prestashop, error404

tengo un error en un prestashop del cual no he encontrado ninguna info en internet.
Me muestra las **cabeceras de error 404 en todas las páginas**, pero las páginas se muestran de forma correcta. Pero claro, hay que corregir este error por motivos de SEO. Aquí un extensión de chrome que muestra el estado de las cabeceras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También se puede controlar con una simple consulta php: *print_r(get_headers('http://bioarray.es/es/info/aviso-legal-20'));*
Que nos mostrará un array con: [0] => HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

La única particularidad de este prestashop es que tiene integrado un wordpress. He visto (e intentando corregir) ese posible error con wordpress, pero no encuentro explicación a que se muestre en todas las páginas de prestashop (y no solo en las del blog).

He realizado una busqueda en los archivos del servidor, y he comentado en todos los controllers y en la clase Tools, donde aparece "header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');", y después de borrar caché varias veces, sigue teniendo el status 404.

¿Alguien tiene idea o sabe cómo depurar este error?
La página en cuestión: http://bioarray.es

¡Cualquier idea será agradecida!

Comment: Habla de wordpress pero igual te da alguna idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921211/404-header-response-but-page-displays-ok

Comment: Revisa el .htaccess y el funcionamiento del mod_rewrite

Comment: Muchas gracias Fly por tus respuestas. Probé excluyendo el wp-blog-header.php del wordpress, pero no funcionó. El mod_rewrite creo que funiona bien, además tengo varios prestashops en ese server y todos van bien. En el .htaccess también comenté la única redirección al 404 que tiene, y nada. Lo más raro de este asunto es que pone la cabecera 404 pero no hace ninguna redirección porque las páginas las muestra bien y no sé cómo depurarlo o rastrear de dónde viene.

Comment: ¿cual fue la solución?

Comment: Pues no encontré la solución óptima porque no encontré la raíz del problema :( Así que a grandes males, grandes remedios. Forcé un status 200 siempre que no existiera un error real, como un 404 o un 500, etc.

Comment: Vaya!!! siento escuchar eso..... si te decides a continuar con el tema algún día, dame un toque por si puedo ayudar.

Comment: Gracias Fly! Un saludo.